# How to create folder listing

Tags: java, swing

Which components, containers or layouts should I use to have left hand side click-able folder structure as shown in the picture? Is it possible to do it with Swing?

left hand side = place which marked as favorite.

As an second question, how can I put search icon in the jtextField like shown in the search place, top-right-hand-side?

[image]

Comment: I have tried to put JPanel then put Jtree on it, but formed windows does not look like as in picture.

Comment: see this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui

Comment: @blackbishop As I said, I donot want tree representation. I want what favorite section graphically has. Your link totally based on tree representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to hack JtextField with icon and search key. In [this website](http://gmigdos.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/java-a-custom-jtextfield-for-searching/), it tells how to put icon on text field.

Comment: I took a quick look at the link you provided for the icon text field and I don't like that the `setMargin()` method is used in the `paintComponent()` method. A painting method should be for painting only and should not change a property of the component. Changing a property can result in an infinite loop since the component automatically tries to repaint itself whenever a property is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably use a `JList` or `JTable` to display the folder names. Read the appropriate section from the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) on `How to use Lists` and `How to Use Tables` for more information. You would need to create a custom renderer to display both the icon and the text. Then you can add a `ListSelectionListener` to handle the selection of a specific folder.

Also for the icon in the text field you could check out [ComponentBorder](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/) or [Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) for possible solutions.